# How do I return an image from a java bean through an AJAX call?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a jsp that makes an AJAX call to a helper jsp which calls a java bean that creates an image. The helper JSP then loads the image into a byte array encodes it to Base64 using Apache commons and returns the string.

```
File imageFile = new File("test.png");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(imageFile.length()));
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)imageFile.length()]; // 32k buffer
int offset = 0;
while ( offset < buffer.length ) {
    int count = is.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length - offset);
    offset += count;
}
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(buffer);
String encodedFile = Base64.encodeBase64String(encoded);
out.print(encodedFile);
out.flush();
```

Here is the javascript that makes and receives the request for the image:

```
function getContourImage(startDate, stopDate){
    $.ajax("services/contour.jsp", {
        data: {
          startDate: startDate,
          stopDate: stopDate
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true, 
        success: contourImageHandler()
    });
}
function contourImageHandler(resp){
    alert("resp: " + resp);
    $( "#plot" ).attr("src","data:image/png;base64," + resp);
}
```

This is the image display area in the html:

```html
<div id="imageDisplay" name="imageDisplayDiv"
    img name="contourImageLocation"
    id="plot" src="images/test.png" width="1200" height="1200">
```

I can see the response in the firebug panel and it seems to have data. The alert statement in the ajax response handler says the response is undefined and no image is placed in the plot location. Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Looks like you didn't sent the `data` argument to `contouImageHandler` in your ajax call.

Comment: You are already invoking your success handlers (`success: contourImageHandler()`) whereas you should do it like this: `success: contourImageHandler`.

Comment: When I use the syntax (success: contourImageHandler ) I don't get the alert popping up to tell me the contourImageHandler function is being called whereas when I use (success: contourImageHandler() ) I do. Though the result with either syntax is the same, the image is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'displaying the image' part of your problem you can go through this:
http://danielmclaren.com/node/90

Also, it would be better if 'helper jsp' work is moved to a Servlet as you may get additional/junk spaces and line breaks in a jsp response.